# Find duplicate values among multiple columns across different rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dataset with multiple columns that look similar to this:

```
ID1     ID2     ID3      ID4
Blue    Grey    Fuchsia  Green
Black   Blue    Orange   Blue
Green   Green   Yellow   Pink
Pink    Yellow  NA       Orange
```

What I want to do is count how many times each value is duplicated across the four columns. For example, this is what I'd like to get back from the above:

```
ID      Replicates   
Blue    3       
Black   1    
Green   3       
Pink    2
Grey    1
Yellow  2
Fuchsia 1 
Orange  2
```

I'd also like to be able to ask which ID value is present in the data set at frequency >2. So the expected result would be: Green and Blue.

Any thoughts on how to do this in Oracle? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select c, count(*)
from
(
select ID1 as c from tablename
union all
select ID2 as c from tablename
union all
select ID3 as c from tablename
union all
select ID4 as c from tablename
)
group by c
```

Add `HAVING count(*) > 2` at the end to get only Green and Blue.

Comment: Thank You! the above query works if "as dt" is removed from the query. Else it is showing the "SQL command not properly ended" error. Also , Can you explain the logic of this query?

Comment: `as dt` removed. (ANSI SQL, but Oracle doesn't like it...) The sub-query (a derived table) simply returns all data as one column. The GROUP BY is there to do the counting. (And HAVING is used to restrict the result to only colors that appears more than twice.)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) FROM(
SELECT ID1 ID FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT ID2 ID FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT ID3 ID FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT ID4 ID FROM TBL ) Q
GROUP BY Q.ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, sum(id_cnt)
(select ID1 as ID,count(*) as id_cnt from tableA group by ID1
union all
select ID2,count(*)from tableA group by ID2
union all
select ID3,count(*)from tableA group by ID3
union all
select ID4,count(*)from tableA group by ID4)
group by id
```

Outpout will be similar to

```
ID      Replicates   
Blue    3       
Black   1    
Green   3       
Pink    2
Grey    1
Yellow  2
Fuchsia 1 
Orange  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another very straight-forward option using Oracle's `unpivot` keyword:

```
select id, count(*) as replicates
from tbl
unpivot
(
  id for original_column_name in (id1, id2, id3, id4)  
)
group by id
```

... and of course, you can add a `having` and/or `order by` clause as you please.